# Migrate flat jsonb to hstore

Tags: postgresql, hstore, jsonb

I run postgres 9.4, and want to migrate column in my database table to hstore just to be able to make performance comparison.

My current column is key-value pair in jsonb, w/o nested structure.

Any tips how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table jsons (id int, val jsonb);
insert into jsons values
(1, '{"age":22}'), 
(2, '{"height":182}'),
(3, '{"age":30, "height":177}');
```

Split json objects to `key`, `value` pairs:

```
    select id, (jsonb_each_text(val)).key, (jsonb_each_text(val)).value
    from jsons

 id |  key   | value 
----+--------+-------
  1 | age    | 22
  2 | height | 182
  3 | age    | 30
  3 | height | 177
(4 rows)
```

Aggregate the pairs and convert them to hstore:

```
select id, hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
from (
    select id, (jsonb_each_text(val)).key, (jsonb_each_text(val)).value
    from jsons
    ) sub
group by 1
order by 1

 id |            hstore            
----+------------------------------
  1 | "age"=>"22"
  2 | "height"=>"182"
  3 | "age"=>"30", "height"=>"177"
(3 rows)
```

The same can be accomplished in a more elegant way using lateral join:

```
select id, hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value))
from jsons
cross join jsonb_each_text(val)
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Comment: the last code snippet was the one that helped me, as well as you. thanks also for others for your step by step guidance

Comment: The first one was only to illustrate the second (to better understand the query). You're welcome.